# htaccess: redirect article one level deeper without loop

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-redirect

I have a url like this:

https://example.com/product/my-product-name

I need to redirect to:

https://example.com/product/**item**/my-product-name

I tried multiple solutions, also solutions I've found here on SO, but I ended up on infinite loops when I accessed /product (which shall NOT redirect) and also multiple redirects when I called the "old" product.

So:
https://example.com/product/**item**/my-product-name

shall **NOT** redirect.

https://example.com/product/my-product-name
**shall** redirect to 
https://example.com/product/**item**/my-product-name

and

https://example.com/product/ and https://example.com/product shall NOT redirect.

Can anybody help me on this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this redirect rule your **topmost rule** in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(product)/(?!item/)(.+)$ /$1/item/$2 [L,NE,R=301]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this change.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work out, but I found another solution which worked for me. I am on my phone right now so I can’t post the solution but I’ll update it once I’m back on my computer.

Comment: I found one mistake in this answer and fixed it. Please try it out once more.